# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I can't import `Keras` in PyCharm IDE on a Mac. I have tried installing and uninstalling Keras using both `pip`, `pip3`, `conda`, and easy install, but none worked. I have tried changing interpreters (Python 2.7 and 3.6) but neither worked.

In a terminal, when I run:

> pip3 list | grep -i keras

I get:

> Keras                              2.2.2
>   Keras-Applications                 1.0.4
>   Keras-Preprocessing                1.0.2

I think this means that my Keras installation was successful. I have also checked my environment with:

> python3 -c 'import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)'

I get:

> '/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
>    '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
>    '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>    '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
>    '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa']

I have tried running:

> python -c "import keras"

I get:

> Using TensorFlow backend.

But when I run/import Keras on the `PyCharm` IDE, I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

What should I do to run Keras on a Mac with `PyCharm 3.6`?

Comment: "Using TensorFlow backend." means keras is imported correctly.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my post, the problem is when I import keras in IDE i get import error.

Comment: can you check python interpreter in pycharm, and while selecting interpreter you can see list of packages installed. check whether keras is there or not @dm5

Comment: I just run pip list, keras packages are installed @Asif Mohamed

Comment: try opening terminal in  pycharm. and check sys.path is correct or not. you might have picked wrong interpreter. @dm5.

Comment: the keras folder in my home directory is hidden. I am not sure if this may be the problem. It is a .keras folder which shows what is my backend. There is no any other folder related to keras @Asif Mohammed

Comment: @dm5 i think you are not understood what i am saying. press alt + f12. then check  keras is in pip list or not

Answer (score 1):

I think this has a relation with the environment the `pycharm` using 
try to install Keras using `pycharm` terminal

in pycharm terminal apply the following

```
pip install Keras
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24677125)

Comment: it is simple I mean  use the terminal to install using pip install Keras on pycharm instead of the terminal on ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

When you start a project in PyCharm, there is an option to use an existing virtual environment or create a new virtual environment. If nothing mentioned while creating the project, new virtual environment will be created. If that is the case, there is no Keras in the new environment which is possibly your issue.
 It will be better to do this installation in some virtual environments and use it accordingly in Pycharm.